# How to post javascript data to a rails controller action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using [jQuery Shapeshift](https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift) for drag and drop ordering for some lists that i have. All i need is to send or post this data below to my rails controller action so i can update the order.

This is what i get in my console each time i drag a list.

```
list_46
0
list_45
1
list_38
2
list_44
3
list_39
4
list_37
5
```

This is the exact path that i need to send that data above to. I have my routes setup correctly.

```
sortlists_boards POST  /boards/sortlists(.:format)
```

Javascript Code

```
jQuery(function() {
  $('.listwrap').shapeshift();
  return $('.listwrap').on('ss-rearranged', function(e) {
    $(this).children().each(function() {
      #I need to send/post these two lines below to sortlists_boards_path 
      console.log($(this).attr("id"))
      console.log($(this).index())    
    });
  });
});
```

Some Github issues that might help

https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift/issues/64

https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift/issues/88

https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift/issues/48

Comment: could you provide the output of your `rake routes` please? sortlists_boards is the named route but its unclear what the endpoint looks like

Comment: I updated my question.  sortlists_boards POST  /boards/sortlists(.:format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, modify your Javascript to create an array of ordered pairs and send it to your endpoint:

```
jQuery(function() {
  $('.listwrap').shapeshift();
  $('.listwrap').on('ss-rearranged', function(e) {
    ordered_items = [];
    $(this).children().each(function() {
      ordered_items.push([$(this).attr("id"), $(this).index()]);
    });
    $.post('/boards/sortlists',
      {ordered_items: JSON.stringify(ordered_items)},
      function(data, status, jqXHR) {
      // This is what gets rendered from your rails controller + action
    });
  });
});
```

Then, review what it looks like on the Rails side and do something with it

```
class BoardsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def sortlists
    logger.info params[:ordered_items]
  end
  # ...
end
```

The output of that will go to log/development.log

Comment: Hmmm i get 500 (internal server error) I had this exact thing working with Jquery Sortable but i can't figure out how to do this with shapeshift. I used this with Jquery Sortable`$.post($(this).data('update-list'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))` but shapeshift says you can't serialize https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift/issues/64

Comment: Ok it's was because i had to add  `render nothing: true` to my sortlists method. That fixed the server error. It doesn't work though when i look in my rails terminal it says Parameters: {"ordered_items"=>"[]"} but nothing changes when i drag a list to a different order. Nothing shows up in my log.

Comment: can you console.log(ordered_items) before on the post request on the client side to see if there's anything in there?

Comment: your right theres is nothing there i can't get this part to work with your code `return $('.listwrap').on('ss-rearranged', function(e) { });` can you update your post with all the javascript that i had. Maybe i am using the wrong syntax or something. This is why there is nothing in it.

Answer (score 0):

Create/Update a JavaScript object on each drag and drop and send an ajax request to the controller, where u can read the object and store in the database.